# What is another way to say "in my opinion"?

Tags: phrase-requests

What phrase should I use to prevent the redundancy of saying "*In my opinion...*"?

Oftentimes, I always say this phrase whenever my teacher asks for my opinion about certain subject or topic and it sounds a little redundant and annoying.
Is there any alternative to say the above-mentioned phrase? -- Alternative, in a way, that it will sound witty.

Comment: I think, in my estimation, according to me,  to my way of thinking, what I say is, my thought is, in my esteemed (or not so esteemed) opinion, after much deliberation (or at least for the last 2 seconds)  I have concluded that...

Comment: After having consulted with Athena [goddess of wisdom] we have concluded...,   Anyone who knows anything will agree that...

Comment: "I feel", "I believe", "it was handed down to me from on high that ...".

Comment: If someone asks you for your opinion, you don't need to start with a modal pragmatic marker echoing their request. You may need to adjust the degree of certainty you wish to convey with a different marker (It's just possible that ... / It is certain that ...).

Comment: As what as my existence say. or As what my guts force me to tell.

Answer (score 9):

- As I see it
- it seems to me
- It seems likely
- I have observed
- One can postulate
- In my experience
- As far as I can tell
- Consider this:
- You can see that
- One might argue that
- the evidence can lead one to conclude

Comment: Although this list offers possible alternatives, unlike other Q. & A. websites, Stack Exchange isn't only concerned with answering the question. [We prefer answers that corroborate their validity with facts, references or expertise and more importantly, explain why and how they are good](http://tinyurl.com/kz3nym8). This answer does nothing to explain why they are valid alternatives, let alone how they are good ones. Some of them don't seem to be very good suggestions. [Experience](http://tinyurl.com/mlyng57) and [opinion](http://tinyurl.com/l4cp38m) are two very distinct concepts for example!

Comment: As what as my existence say. or As what my guts force me to tell.

Answer (score 3):

"I think" is a strong yet simple start as noted in the initial comment.

But another technique is first repeating back the subject in such a way you demonstrate a thorough understanding of the question. And the subject.

In the fields of debating and rhetoric lots of inspiration can be found.

Have fun!

Some references

http://persuasivespeechideas.org/famous-persuasive-speeches/
http://debate-central.ncpa.org/the-12-best-debate-tips-weve-ever-heard/
http://www.miracosta.cc.ca.us/home/dperales/NEWRhetorical%20Strategies.htm
http://literarydevices.net/discourse/

Comment: Great orators and debaters will avoid saying things like "in my opinion" or "I think" for obvious reasons. A noteable exception is Churchill saying *"I expect that the battle of Britain is about to begin."* at the beginning of "their finest hour" speech. But that's a rare exception in all those links (which are very good by the way) . The general rule is going to be: don't say anything like that.

Comment: First 3 of 4 reference links failed to work.

Answer (score 3):

To my mind, "**to my mind**" can work in lieu of "in my opinion".

Futhermore, and from my standpoint/perspective, "**from my standpoint/perspective**" can also work in lieu of "in my opinion"...

And since I cannot comment on Nickys answer, I'll add here:

"**By my reckoning**"

Answer (score 2):

"I reckon"? I use that a lot. Also sounds pretty sophisticated ;)

Comment: Haha. Very British.

Comment: Actually, in the US "I reckon" would likely be considered a rural dialect thing.

Answer (score 2):

As anotherdave said, don't say it unless it needs to be said. If someone has asked for your opinion then beginning with "In *my* opinion" is redundant (but better than saying "uhmm" or "errr").

For those times when it is appropriate then I suggest:

**"It seems to me that..."**

This takes a little longer to say than "I think that" or "I reckon that" so give a little more thinking time. "It seems to me" comes across as far more matter-of-fact but really means the same thing - just with more confidence. It seems to put the onus of truth on the statement (on the thing making you think that) rather than yourself. If it turns out that you are wrong you can blame how it seemed rather than your opinion.

**"It occurs to me that..."** is even more matter-of-fact but still not completely. The listener would expect the following words to be true. However, you have a get-out clause if it turns out that they are not: you did say "to me".

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, nothing — as you said, "in my opinion" is mostly a redundant phrase, as people normally assume your giving your own personal opinion anyway:

> - In my opinion, *Star Wars* is better than *Star Trek*
> - In my opinion, Galway is a nicer city than London

Both of these are clearly quite subjective & don't need any qualifying phrase.

The times to use "in my opinion" are (in my opinion) when your personal view could be misunderstood as something other than a personal standpoint.

> - French is easier to learn than Mandarin, in my opinion — Prof. So-and-so, head of Linguistics department.
> - In my opinion, the presenter should have worn a poppy on Remembrance Sunday — Director General of the BBC

Here respectively, people are saying that:

- they're not presenting something as fact given their professional background or
- they're ot presenting something as company policy, only their own personal point of view.