# Other words for "it seems to me"

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, phrases, idioms

Can I use the phrase **it seems to me that** in a sentence where I intend to state my opinion. Why? If not, can you suggest other words to replace it (but still has the same meaning.)

Comment: Yes, you can indeed use it that way.

Comment: You can indeed use that or you can also say, `in my opinion....`, or if you're deducing something then a phrase like `I think it follows that ....`

Comment: or a more formal tone with- "it appears to me"

Comment: It seems to me that this is OK.

Comment: I have already posted the same question as this. You can use "it occurs to me that...", "The way I see it is...". Visit the link for more alternatives. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/256887/what-is-another-way-to-say-in-my-opinion

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is perfectly fine. [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/it-seems) provides the following example:

> **it seems to someone (that)**: *It seems to me this is his most important novel.*

It's listed under the idiom **it seems** for which they provide the following definition:

> used for saying that something appears to exist or be true

This definition fits, because the following phrases have similar meaning, according to [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/appear+to) (the examples are mine; not taken from the dictionary):

> It **seems to me** that this question has been overlooked for a long time.
>
> It **appears to me** that this question has been overlooked for a long time.

Attribution: "It Seems (phrase) Definition and Synonyms | Macmillan Dictionary."  American English Definition and Synonyms | Macmillan Dictionary. Accessed June 01, 2018. https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/it-seems.

Answer (score 1):

"it seems to me that" is perfectly fine. **Depending on context**, there are other ways to convey almost the same:

- "It looks like"
- "I'm inclined to think that"
- "I presume"
- "I presuppose"
- "I take for granted"
- "I have the impression"

Examples:

> - "Tut, it looks like there's something wrong here."
> - "I'm inclined to think he doesn't know his subject."
> - "I presume they will end up staying for dinner."
> - "I presuppose the measurements were accurate."
> - "I take it for granted she has some connections and could help us."